# ¿Cómo imponer condiciones al ajustar una curva?

Tags: r, data

Estoy intentando ajustar una serie de puntos a una función de la forma `f(A)=a·(1-exp(-21.6·A))+b·A+c·A^2+d·A^3`. Quiero que esta función satisfaga la condición `f(1)=1`, entonces, dado que `exp(-21.6)` es pequeño, aproximo esta condición como `d=1-a-b-c`.

El problema es que quiero que la función `f(A)-A` no tenga ningún cero en el intervalo `(0,1)`. Haciendo un poco de cálculo, esto significa que tenemos ciertas cotas superiores (o inferiores) para a, b y c, pero no sé como imponer estas condiciones para el ajuste de la curva (o si existe otro método mejor de hacerlo) ni en `Maple` ni en `R`, que son los programas que uso para esta clase de tareas, ya que fijar condiciones iniciales no sirve para resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola @rodrigo-crespo-miguel estas en StackOverflow en **Español**, traduce tu pregunta o haz la consulta en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Disculpas, pensaba que estaba en la página general. Ya lo he editado para traducirlo al castellano. Un saludo.

Comment: No me acuerdo mucho, pero para poner restricciones se utiliza el comando optim en R con los argumentos upper y lower.